# 2 If clauses in one sentence

Tags: conditionals, clauses

Saying this sentence sounds okay to me, but looking at it seems wrong.  Could someone enlighten me by correcting this sentence for me?

"*Could you ask him how much lumbar herniated disc surgery typically is; and also, if he can give me a discount, if he is willing to do the surgery himself.*"

Comment: "Could you ask him how much lumbar herniated disc surgery typically is –
 and also (if he is willing to do the surgery himself) whether he could give me a discount?"

Answer (score 1):

Could you ask him how much lumbar herniated disc surgery typically is; and also, if he is willing to do the surgery himself, can he give me a discount.

Comment: thanx!  but this sounds a little weird to me.  

how about 
Could you ask him how much lumbar herniated disc surgery typically is; and also, CAN HE** give me a discount if he is willing to do the surgery himself.

can anyone give me an example IF THERE IS ONE for a sentence with 2 if clauses?